# masking segmented object and remove video background in python

Tags: python, object, video, background, rgb

I would like to detect object within video and remove the background of it. I want the detected object showed in the same format in RGB not in a binary format. I have the following code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame_width = int(video_capture.get(3))
frame_height = int(video_capture.get(4))
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4',-1, 10, (frame_width,frame_height), True)
time.sleep(3)
background = 0

while (video_capture.isOpened()):
    ret, image = video_capture.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    image = np.flip(image, axis=1)
    # Change to HSV
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Create masks with coordinates to detect the color
    lower_blue = np.array([94, 80, 2])
    upper_blue = np.array([126, 255, 255])
    mask_all = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
    mask_all = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_all, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))
    mask_all = cv2.morphologyEx(mask_all, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8))

    # Hide the blue part away
    mask2 = cv2.bitwise_not(mask_all)
    streamA = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask2)  # Copy the masked area's original part
    streamB = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask=mask_all)

    # Write the video in the file specified in the previous block
    output = cv2.addWeighted(streamA, 1, streamB, 1, 0)
    out.write(output)
    cv2.imshow("cloak_trick", output)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) == 13:
        break

video_capture.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error when I try to implement it.

```
streamB = cv2.bitwise_and(background, background, mask=mask_all)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.6.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:230: 
error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'cv::binary_op'

fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 000C
OpenCV: FFMPEG: format mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)
fourcc tag 0x31637661/'avc1' codec_id 001B
fourcc tag 0x33637661/'avc3' codec_id 001B
fourcc tag 0x31766568/'hev1' codec_id 00AD
fourcc tag 0x31637668/'hvc1' codec_id 00AD
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0002
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0001
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0007
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 003D
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 0058
fourcc tag 0x312d6376/'vc-1' codec_id 0046
fourcc tag 0x63617264/'drac' codec_id 0074
fourcc tag 0x7634706d/'mp4v' codec_id 00A3
fourcc tag 0x39307076/'vp09' codec_id 00A7
fourcc tag 0x31307661/'av01' codec_id 801D
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15002
fourcc tag 0x63616c61/'alac' codec_id 15010
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 1502D
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15001
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15000
fourcc tag 0x332d6361/'ac-3' codec_id 15003
fourcc tag 0x332d6365/'ec-3' codec_id 15028
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15004
fourcc tag 0x61706c6d/'mlpa' codec_id 1502C
fourcc tag 0x43614c66/'fLaC' codec_id 1500C
fourcc tag 0x7375704f/'Opus' codec_id 1503C
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15005
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15018
fourcc tag 0x6134706d/'mp4a' codec_id 15803
fourcc tag 0x7334706d/'mp4s' codec_id 17000
fourcc tag 0x67337874/'tx3g' codec_id 17005
fourcc tag 0x646d7067/'gpmd' codec_id 18807
fourcc tag 0x316d686d/'mhm1' codec_id 15817
```

Can anyone please help me how can I fix it. Or help me with another code return the same RGB objects from video and remove it's background. I will be very thankful.

Comment: I don't use Python so you tell me: Is this code allowed? `cv2.bitwise_and( 0, 0, mask=mask_all)`? Because your `background = 0` instead being a pixel array...

Comment: Use `mp4v` FOURCC instead of `-1`: `out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height), True)` and initialize `background` to NumPy array: `background = np.zeros((frame_height, frame_width, 3), np.uint8)`.